# How do I store more than 15,000 Japanese characters in a column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to store more than 15,000 characters of Japanese text in a SQL Server 2008 database. We have a front end tool that will display this text.

Answer (score 4):

In this case only [NVARCHAR(MAX)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158.aspx) should be used. It's able to store up to 2^31-1 bytes of Unicode data (about 2 GB).